# Can't get numbers to swap in my JQuery function when I swap table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jquery function that allows me to click on the UP arrow and it swaps rows in a table.  I have rank numbers in each row.  But I can only get the clicked number to change.  I want both numbers to swap.  I know it is something with getting the value in abovecnt.  I just can't figure out how to get that value of the row above.  Right now it is just undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/2rmowem4/15/

```
$('.change-rank').click(function() {
var cnt = $(this).attr('cnt');                                                       
var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction'),
    $original = $(this).closest("tr"),
    $target = direction === "up" ? $original.prev() : $original.next();

if ( $target.length && direction === "up" ) {
    $original.insertBefore($target);
    abovecnt = $original.find('.ranky input[type="text"]').val();
    $('#rank_' + cnt).val(cnt-1);
    $('#rank_' + abovecnt).val(cnt);
    alert('abovecnt=' + abovecnt + '|cnt=' + cnt);      
}
else if( $target.length ) {
    $original.insertAfter($target);
}
});
```

Note: I'll eventually want the down arrow to swap also, but right now just trying to get it to work.

Comment: So where is the up and down arrows in the fiddle?

Comment: if you're going to store values in custom attributes.. use data attributes http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: better yet, use jQuery.data() which uses a data object and does the data attributes.. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Oh darn, I put the wrong jsfiddle link.  I edited this question and fixed it.  Should be: http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/2rmowem4/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your `cnt` attributes to data attributes for this.

EDIT: updated JS snippet to @tripleb 's recommendation: `before` and `after` .. as opposed to doing inserts and changing values of the arrows.

---

### Sample Code Snippet

```js
  $('.change-rank.up').click(function(ev) {   
    var $original = $(this).closest("tr"),   
        $target = $original.prev();
   
  
    if ($target.length) {
        var cnt = $original.data('cnt'),
            targetcnt = $target.data("cnt");
        if (targetcnt) {
            $original.after($target);
            alert(targetcnt);
        }
    }
 });


 $('.change-rank.down').click(function(ev) {   
    var $original = $(this).closest("tr"),  
        $target = $original.next();
        
    if ($target.length) {
        var cnt = $original.data('cnt'),
            targetcnt = $target.data("cnt");
        if (targetcnt) {
            $original.before($target);
            alert(targetcnt);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
 .change-rank.up:after { 
     content: attr(data-icon);
 }
 .change-rank.down:after { 
     content: attr(data-icon);
 }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Username</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cnt='1'>
        <td><a href='#' class='change-rank up' data-icon="&#9650;"></a>&nbsp;
            <a href='#' class='change-rank down' data-icon="&#9660;"></a>1</td>
        <td>Joey</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='rank_1' class='ranky' value='1' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cnt='2'>
        <td><a href='#' class='change-rank up' data-icon="&#9650;"></a>&nbsp;
            <a href='#' class='change-rank down' data-icon="&#9660;"></a>2</td>
        <td>Randy</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='rank_2' class='ranky' value='2'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cnt='3'>
        <td><a href='#' class='change-rank up' data-icon="&#9650;"></a>&nbsp;
            <a href='#' class='change-rank down' data-icon="&#9660;"></a>3</td>
        <td>Bobby</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='rank_3' class='ranky' value='3' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cnt='4'>
        <td><a href='#' class='change-rank up' data-icon="&#9650;"></a>&nbsp;
            <a href='#' class='change-rank down' data-icon="&#9660;"></a>4</td>
        <td>Jesse</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='rank_4' class='ranky' value='4' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JsFiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2rmowem4/22/)

Comment: @Thread7, no problem.. note that I put the `data-icon` attribute on the hyperlinks as well.. it's unnecessary, but I would recommend using **FontAwesome** or a similar css icon library/solution for this.. these assets are generally just referenced by the html `class` attribute. I added the css `:after` and `:before` pseudos to allude to this underline pattern.

Answer (score 1):

why not this:

```
if ( $target.length && direction === "up" ) {
    $original.after($target)    
}
else if( $target.length ) {
    $original.before($target);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rmowem4/16/

Comment: with jquery if you insert an element in one place it moves it from it's previous position